# How to use lapply in R to evaluate elements of a list?

Tags: r, list, lapply

My apologies if this has been answered somewhere else. I've defined two functions in R and then nested them with good results. Now I would like to evaluate these two nested functions by changing a variable in the second function. I've tried creating a `list` for the changing variable and then using `lapply` to evaluate each element, but I'm getting an error.

My code looks something like this:

```
# First function 
FirstFun <- function(a, b, c, d) {
      answer1 <- (a + b)/(1-(0.2*(c/d))-(0.8*(c/d)^2))
      return(answer1)
}
# First function evaluated 
FirstFun(13,387,1728,1980)

# Second function
SecondFun <- function(answer1,c,d) {
      answer2 <- answer1*(1-(0.2*(c/d))-(0.8*(c/d)^2))
      return(answer2)
}

# Nested function evaluated 
SecondFun(FirstFun(13,387,1728,1980),1728,1980)

# Nested function evaluated with elements of a list
c <- list(0:1980)
lapply(c, SecondFun(FirstFun(13,387,1728,1980),c,1980))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I under stand you correctly  - you are looking for :

```
SecondFun(FirstFun(13,387,1728,1980),0:1980,1980)
```

or maybe this :

```
SecondFun(FirstFun(13,387,1728,0:1980),0:1980,1980)
```

both return a numeric vector of length 1981.

2 things - 
1. no need for a list. a range would work. 
2. calling a variable 'c' is a bad idea..... c is reserved